# NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:hive

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dialect

```
 from pandas import Series, DataFrame
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import datetime
    from pyhive import hive
    from dateutil.rrule import rrule,MONTHLY
    #from sqlalchemy import create_engine,*
    from sqlalchemy import *


    spark_url = "hive://hdfs@10.2.1.45:100015/x1111_ods"
    spark_conn = create_engine(spark_url)
```

but it is notice the error below: please help, my environment is anaconda 2.7

> NoSuchModuleError                          Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        12 
>        13 spark_url = "hive://hdfs@10.2.1.45:100015/x1111_ods"
>   ---> 14 spark_conn = create_engine(spark_url)
>        15 
>        16 import matplotlib as mpl
>
> /home/gang.liu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/**init**.pyc
>   in create_engine(*args, **kwargs)
>       417         `(sql, *multiparams, **params)`, to which the `mock` strategy will
>       418         dispatch all statement execution. Used only by `strategy='mock'`.
>   --> 419 
>       420     """
>       421
>
> /home/gang.liu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.pyc
>   in create(self, name_or_url, **kwargs)
>        54         u.query.pop('plugin', None)
>        55         kwargs.pop('plugins', None)
>   ---> 56 
>        57         entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
>        58         dialect_cls = entrypoint.get_dialect_cls(u)
>
> /home/gang.liu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.pyc
>   in _get_entrypoint(self)
>       148         This is normally the dialect itself except in the case when the
>       149         returned class implements the get_dialect_cls() method.
>   --> 150 
>       151         """
>       152         if '+' not in self.drivername:
>
> /home/gang.liu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.pyc
>   in load(self, name)
>       219         raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
>       220             "Can't load plugin: %s:%s" %
>   --> 221             (self.group, name))
>       222 
>       223     def register(self, name, modulepath, objname):
>
> NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:hive